# Apply find_peaks() function using groupby() in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I have a timeseries data that is grouped by in `ID` column.

I tried using the following code:

```
def find_peaks_in_group(group):
    peaks, peak_properties = find_peaks(group['RFPower'], prominence=1, height=0.7)
    group['peaks'] = False
    group.loc[peaks, 'peaks'] = True
    group['peak_heights'] = 0.0
    group.loc[peaks, 'peak_heights'] = peak_properties['peak_heights']
    return group

result_df=df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(find_peaks_in_group)
```

However Im getting a KeyError:

> None of [Int64Index([76116, 76134, 76146, 76150, 76155, 76161, 76165,
> 76171, 76177, 76180, 76182, 76185, 76187, 76192, 76196, 76201, 76220,
> 76224, 76230, 76235, 76240, 76242, 76247, 76252, 76257, 76276, 76282,
> 76286, 76292, 76295, 76297, 76302, 76307, 76337, 76348, 76350, 76362,
> 76364, 77324, 93723, 94851, 94855], dtype='int64')] are in the
> [index]"

I even tried removing the `group_keys=False` and resetting the index to no avail.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think peaks is list of np.array(index) returned on find_peaks function so you have to use peaks[0] or change returned values of find_peaks